# Adding CSS custom style failed in Rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

im trying to add a custom CSS table alignment in my rails application. But it just doesnt seem to work. Can anyone help me please? Im new to web developing. Im learning HTML, CSS and Rails simultaneously.
Here is my app/assessts/stylesheets/custom.css

```
td {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

And i've included style tag in my head tag. Here my app/views/layout/application.html.haml

```
!!!
%html
  %head
    %title
      = content_for?(:title) ? yield(:title) : "GentelellaOnRails"
    = stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true
    = stylesheet_link_tag 'custom'
    = javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true
    = csrf_meta_tags
    %meta{:content => "width=device-width, initial-scale=1", :name => "viewport"}/
  %body.nav-md
    .container.body
      .main_container
        - flash.each do |key, value|
          #flash{:align => "center", :class => "alert alert-#{key}"}= value
        = render "partials/sidenav"
        = render "partials/topnav"
        .right_col{:role => "main"}
          = yield
        = render "partials/footer"
        = javascript_include_tag 'footermanifest', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true
```

And here's my index file :

```
%h1 Listing all patients

.x_panel
  .x_content
    = link_to 'New Patient', new_patient_path, class: "btn btn-primary"

    %table.table.table-bordered
      %thead
        %tr
          %th Id
          %th Image
          %th Name
          %th Email
          %th Address
          %th Phone
          %th Gender
          %th Birthdate
          %th Bloodgroup
          %th Options

      %tbody
        - @patients.each do |patient|
          %tr
            %td= patient.id
            %td= image_tag patient.image_url.to_s, :size => "100x80"
            %td= patient.name
            %td= patient.email
            %td= patient.address
            %td= patient.phone
            %td= patient.gender
            %td= patient.birthdate
            %td= patient.bloodgroup
            %td
              = link_to edit_patient_path(patient), class: "btn btn-warning" do  
                = fa_icon 'pencil'
              = link_to patient, :method => :delete, :data => { :confirm => 'Are you sure?' }, class: 'btn btn-danger' do 
                = fa_icon 'trash'
```

Comment: are you sure that your css is working? you can check it though using **Inspect Element** in chrome and check the alignments of needed elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

require `custom.css` in `application.css`  eg

## /assets/stylesheets/application.css

```
*= require custom
*= require_tree .
```

and remove line `= stylesheet_link_tag 'custom'` from layouts.

Restart your server.